# Getting (timed out) ModelError from AWS Sagemaker when trying to deploy a custom model to an endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently facing an issue while deploying an endpoint on AWS SageMaker using the PyTorchModel with my custom model. Despite following the example provided on the [official Amazon website](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/hosting-yolov8-pytorch-model-on-amazon-sagemaker-endpoints/) (all codes are available one Github), I'm encountering the following error:

> sagemaker An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (0) from primary with message Your invocation timed out while waiting for a response from container primary. Review the latency metrics for each container in Amazon CloudWatch, resolve the issue, and try again.

I have tried to troubleshoot the problem by reviewing logs in Amazon CloudWatch, but I haven't been able to identify a resolution. I also changed the `SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT` to `180`, but it doesn't work. Please let me know how I can fix it. I have tried other examples and documents on AWS website but none of them worked for me.